# Best practice of Flask route for app.route("/index") or ("/index.html")

Tags: flask

Is there a convention to define app routes in Flask to add suffix ".html"? e.g,

```
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET'])
def index_func(){
    return render_template("index.html")
}

@app.route("/index.html", methods=['GET'])
def index_func(){
    return render_template("index.html")
}
```

Which would be the best practice? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should learn Python first before flask. That's not how you define functions in Python.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice in this case is to use '/' for index and avoid using '/index' and '/index.html' altogether. An index page is another name for a home page which is a synonym for the root page of a site which is '/'. All other routes are necessarily prefixed with it so '/index', '/home', etc are redundant.

As for adding file extensions to routes, this is not only unnecessary but could be miss leading in the future if you want to serve different content types from that route using [content-negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). For example, what if you wanted to serve a JSON version of the same page for mobile and SPA clients? I'm not aware of any sources that state omitting the file extension is a best practice but it's implicit in that every route example in Flask's documentation omits a file extension. For example, the [Rendering Templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) example, which is serving an HTML page, does not include a .html suffix in the route.

Answer (score 1):

No. 1 The way you defined a function in python is wrong.

```
def func(){

}
```

wont work. Instead you would define a function like this:

```
def func():
    print("Hi")
```

Then, coming to the route declaration you would use

```
@app.route("/index")
def index_func():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Also note when you just want to recieve `GET` methods you dont have to specify `methods=['GET']`